# How can i get psycopg2 to work on visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to a database, and it keeps saying no module named 'psycopg2'. I went into my terminal made sure they are both installed. Python version 3.10.2 and psycopg2 version 2.9.3. I have uninstalled and reinstalled psycopg2 and nothing worked.

I have tried opening a new vscode window and just get really basic my doing an import psycopg2 and a connect, but the error still pops up. I also went in windows command prompt and went into python and did a manual import and connect there, and it worked. Now I just need it to work in VScode. When i install again, it says already satisfied psycopg2 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (2.9.6). The warning i get when hovering psycopg2 in vscode says "Import "psycopg2" could not be resolved from sourcePylance" Please help